# Correct use of ios

Tags: c++, ios, function

Which version of function (`myfunc2` or `myfunc3`) is correct in all platform.

```
ostream &myfunc1(ostream &os) const {
  //
  return os;
}
ostream &myfunc2(ostream &os) const {

    os << myfunc1(os);
}

ostream &myfunc3(ostream &os) const {

    os << myfunc1(os).rdbuf();
}
```

Comment: Are you missing a `return` statement from each of `myfunc2` and `myfunc3`?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to access the `rdbuf()` of a stream, which accesses the underlying buffer in the `streambuf`.

Conceptually, an `ostream` is a frontend to a `streambuf`. What you are doing in `myfunc3` is to access the `rdbuf` from `streambuf` directly, bypassing the interface from `ostream`.

This can be done, but it is uncommon. Stick to `myfunc2`, it is the usual way to do it.